# Convert docx to PDF using Linux and Python

Tags: python, linux, pdf, docx, file-conversion

I am looking for a way to convert a docx to PDF using Python in Linux. So far, all I have found that works it is using Windows, is there a way to do it in Python without using libreoffice?

Comment: You can take a look here: https://code.activestate.com/recipes/578795-convert-microsoft-word-files-to-pdf-with-docxtopdf/ maybe that will help. Otherwise there are alternatives you can run in terminal such as Calibre https://calibre-ebook.com/about that doesn't use libreoffice, eg (after install): `ebook-convert test.docx test.pdf`

Comment: @abc it doesn't. Comptypes can't be used in Linux

Comment: @Christoffer but can I use it in a Python script?

Comment: If you really want to, you can use subprocess to call the terminal command, that's one option. Otherwise you can look at the source code since it's open source, take a look here: https://github.com/kovidgoyal/calibre and here https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/plugins.html#module-calibre.customize.conversion

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aspose.Words for Python to convert documents to PDF:

```py
import aspose.words as aw

doc = aw.Document("in.docx")
doc.save("out.pdf")
```